# When installing JQuery what files are altered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

Which files do you modify?

For instance for "Camera" and "RCarousel" they both come with their own associated files. I know I must add code to one page.....but is that page the MASTER file for the information that goes in the heading? or do I only add code to the page where the code is going to go?

Do you also modify any of the existing .css pages for the website, or is all of the information for the slider drawn from it's own associated files?

Comment: Can you narrow down the ambiguity of your question with a more concrete example?

Comment: When adding jQuery, you just place the script rel in the head of your master page.  Just put this in the head: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and you will have access to the jquery library

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add script tags to the html page that need the plugins. You can add these in either the `head` or `body` tag. The order in which you add the tags matters, for instance you must include jQuery before any plugins or scripts that depend on jquery.

For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="myOtherPlugin.js"></script>
        ...other content...
    </head>
    <body>
         ...other content...
    </body>
</html>
```